# Accessing buffer using read() in sockets

Tags: c, sockets

In my socket code I have the following structure:

Server:

```
         #include <stdio.h>
         #include <stdlib.h>
         #include <string.h>
         #include <sys/types.h>
         #include <sys/socket.h>
         #include <netinet/in.h>
         #define MAXPROFILES  2

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
        int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
        unsigned char buf[1024];
        char* pointer = buf;

       struct profile_t
     {
       unsigned char length;
       unsigned char type;
       unsigned char *data;
     };

       typedef struct profile_datagram_t
     {
       unsigned char src[4];
       unsigned char dst[4];
       unsigned char ver;
       unsigned char n;
       struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
     } header;


       header outObj;

       int j =0;
       int i =0;


       if (argc < 2) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s port_number1",argv[0]);
       exit(1);
     }
       sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
       if (sockfd < 0)
       error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket");

       bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
       portno = atoi(argv[1]);

       serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
       serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
          error("ERROR DETECTED !!! There was a problem in binding");

        listen(sockfd, 10);
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);



        printf("Server listening on port number %d...\n", serv_addr.sin_port);

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! the connection request was not accepted");

        int rc = read(newsockfd,&pointer,100);
        if(rc < 0){
        printf("error");
      }
        else {
        printf("success %d",rc);
      }
        for(int i=0;i<29;i++){
        printf(pointer);
        printf(buf);
      }





 return 0;
```

}

Client:

```
            int main(int argc, char *argv[])

         {
            int sockfd, portno, n;
            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            struct hostent *server;
            unsigned char buf[1024];
            unsigned int srcAddress = 2193598184;
            unsigned int destAddress = 2193598182;

           struct profile_t
       {
            unsigned char length;
            unsigned char type;
            unsigned char *data;
       };

            typedef struct profile_datagram_t
       {
            unsigned char src[4];
            unsigned char dst[4];
            unsigned char ver;
            unsigned char n;
            struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
        } header;


           header outObj;

           int j =0;
           int i =0;
      // for loop for doing the malloc so that we can allocate memory to all profiles
           for(i=0;i<MAXPROFILES;i++){
           outObj.profiles[i].data = malloc(5);
        }


          for(i=0;i<4;i++){
          outObj.src[i] = (srcAddress >> (i*8)) & 0xFF;
          outObj.dst[i] = (destAddress >> (i*8)) & 0xFF;
        }
          outObj.ver = 1;
          outObj.n = 2;

          memcpy(buf,&outObj.src,4);
          memcpy(buf+4,&outObj.dst,4);
          memcpy(buf+8,&outObj.ver,1);
          memcpy(buf+9,&outObj.n,2);


          outObj.profiles[0].length = 5;
          outObj.profiles[0].type = 1;
          outObj.profiles[1].length = 5;
          outObj.profiles[1].type = 2;

          for(i=0;i<MAXPROFILES;i++){
          for(j=0;j<5;j++){
          outObj.profiles[i].data[j] = j+1;
        }
      }



            int k = 11;


           for(i=0;i<MAXPROFILES;i++){
            memcpy(buf+k,&outObj.profiles[0].length,1);
            memcpy(buf+k+1,&outObj.profiles[0].type,1);
            memcpy(buf+k+2,outObj.profiles[0].data,5);
            k +=7;
       }


           if (argc < 3) {
           fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
           exit(0);
       }
           portno = atoi(argv[2]); //Convert ASCII to integer
           sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // socket file descriptor


           if (sockfd < 0)
           error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket\n");

           server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
           if (server == NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr,"ERROR DETECTED !!!, no such server found \n");
           exit(0);
       }

           bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); //clear the memory for server  address

           serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
           bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
                 (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
                   server->h_length);

           serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

           printf("Client 1 trying to connect with server host %s on port %d\n", argv[1], portno); 


             if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
             error("ERROR in connection");

             printf("SUCCESS !!! Connection established \n");


             if (write(sockfd, buf, k) < 0)
          {
             error("Write error has occured ");
          }


            return 0;
           }
```

Now from the client side I do a memcpy to my unsigned char buf and send the data. On the recv side how to access the values inside my "buf". I tried the "*" operator, but i get a warning

arning: passing argument 1 of âprintfâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

I want to basically access the values inside buffer, as I know the size i should be able to repopulate my packet back. I know that this is a "C" question and not exactly "socket related". Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you just have to reverse what you've done on the client side:

You're also not gaining anything by using `char *pointer = buf`, just read directly into the buffer.  When you loop around for your `MAXPROFILES`, just check your current position in `buffer` against the returned `size` to make sure you're not reading data you didn't receive.

For example:

```
   int size = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

   int src, dst;
   char ver;
   short n;

   memcpy(&src, buf + 0, 4);
   memcpy(&dst, buf + 4, 4);
   memcpy(&ver, buf + 8, 1);
   memcpy(&n,   buf + 9, 2);
```

...and so on...

You're encoding your structures/data on the client side, so you have to decode them on the server side.  And once you've done so, then you can print them or do whatever it is you like:

```
  printf("src: %d  dst: %d  ver: %c  n: %d\n", src, dst, ver, n);
```

Also, to simplify your encode/decode, use the same method (e.g. `memcpy` instead of your byte-by-byte with masks method).  For example, on the client side:

```
  k = 0;
  memcpy(buf + k, &src, sizeof(src));  k += sizeof(src);
  memcpy(buf + k, &dst, sizeof(dst));  k += sizeof(dst);
  ...
```

This also frees you a bit from hardcoded numbers as I was doing above.  Just make sure your `src`, `dst`, and all the rest have the same type on both the client and server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply...code got complied without one warning...thanks a ton!!!For an unsigned char, as I have used, how to give the printf statement...i mean should it be "%c" or "%d"???

Comment: You can use either `%u` for an unsigned integer or `%h` for an unsigned short.

Answer (score 0):

you mean gcc gave a warning on this line: "int rc = read(newsockfd,&pointer,100);"

your variable "pointer" itself is a pointer to a buf, so you do not need use &pointer, just use like this:

int rc = read(newsockfd,pointer,100)